# NSIS AccessControl Plugin disable access to directory for all except Admins and System

Tags: nsis

I just read bunch of answers about setting permissions to directory by NSIS AccessControl plugin, but all those only show basic usage copy pasted from plugin site... It only shows cases ALL or NOTHING... but how do I disable ALL permissions to directory for everyone except System and Administrators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AccessControl::DisableFileInheritance "$temp\test.tmp"
Pop $0
DetailPrint $0

AccessControl::ClearOnFile "$temp\test.tmp" "(S-1-5-18)" "FullAccess"
Pop $0
DetailPrint $0

AccessControl::SetOnFile "$temp\test.tmp" "(S-1-5-32-544)" "FullAccess"
Pop $0
DetailPrint $0
```

This might not be enough, you should probably also use SetFileOwner and maybe SetFileGroup...

Comment: But it does not disallow anything... I can still see those files under normal user account. Disabling file inheritance is not what I need neither, as I need to disallow normal users to access all files in directory.

Comment: DisableFileInheritance is there to prevent the ACL from the parent directory to allow access. This code works for me, I cannot access the directory or the files in it. If the there are already files in the directory and if they have non-inherited ACE's you need to call this code on those files as well...

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong... hmm... I'll check again later. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: It works fine. Was my mistake. Please edit your answer so I could upvote it.